# How does a browser select a video with multiple sources of same format?

Tags: html, video

I have a video file that's being served like:

```
<video>
  <source src="https://uploads.pew.tube/uploads/meme/Kp2rEJX.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/pewtube/meme/Kp2rEJX.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I'd prefer to serve from my own server but have B2 as a backup, however I'm noticing most of the videos are being served via B2 and not my server even though the server is first in the list of sources, what is going on/why are the browsers selecting B2 over my own server?

Comment: What is B2? and which video is coming from your own server?

Comment: B2 is file hosting much like S3, the first link is my own server